# Magento 1.7 - order item joining with configurable product information

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a grid showing order items. I want to show product details for each item. But some are `simple` and some are `configurable`.

Collection in the grid is `sales/order_item_collection`.

In the `_prepareCollection()` I have these joins:

```
        $collection->getSelect()->join( 
           array('orders_alias' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order'))
           , 'main_table.order_id = orders_alias.entity_id'
           , array('orders_alias.increment_id', 'order_date' => 'orders_alias.created_at')
           , null);

    $collection->getSelect()->join( 
           array('p' => $resource->getTableName('catalog/product'))
           , 'main_table.product_id = p.entity_id
           , array('product_sku' => 'p.sku')
           , null);
```

For an order item having a configurable product I see an extra row.
e.g. if someone buys a shirt in size XXL I see 2 rows for the order items.

I guess I need to only show the visible products. How should I do this?

If I go from an order and show the items I can do this:

```
    // get order items
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

But I need to check from an item to see if it is visible.

Looking at `\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php` I see:

```
    public function getAllVisibleItems()
{
    $items = array();
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if (!$item->isDeleted() && !$item->getParentItemId()) {
            $items[] =  $item;
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

So If I add this filter:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_item_id', array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')));
```

it seems to show the correct order items. Is this the proper way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I use this solution:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_item_id', array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')));
```

Answer (score 0):

where to add this line?

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('parent_item_id', array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')));

I am seeing two items one with 0 and another with actual product

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx1bd.jpg

Comment: I created my own module and in the `Grid.php` I added this in the function `protected function _prepareCollection(){}`